# Can a diff-in-diff be used with IPTW

Tags: difference-in-difference

Can a difference-in-difference test be used with Inverse probability weighting.

Please see my code below

```
psmatch2 treatment covariate1 covariate2 covariate3

gen ipw=1/_pscore if treatment==1
replace ipw=1/(1-_pscore) if treatment==0


reg roa treatment post treatmentxpost i.year .industryyear i.countryyear, vce(cluster firm)
```

Comment: Sure it can.  The question is why you are doing it.

Comment: This is Stata code. Best to explain that.